# After update the latest version I cant run my application

Tags: android, eclipse

[image: cant run application]

[image: I don't understand why there is a project called "appcompat" auto generated when I create a new application]

I don't understand why there is a project called "appcompat" auto generated when I create a new application project.

Also I don't understand why there is a project called "fragment" auto generated when I create a new android activity.

Also what does the exclamation mark mean on my Package Explorer project icon

Comment: I don't understand why do you always have an `Unregistered Version`  red overlay in all your images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, your Eclipse's Error showing that the "Appcombat" is not properly added as library. if you are not using it.

2 suggestions
first:
 "Right Click the Project" ---> Go to Android Tab ---> remove this library reference

Second:
  Clean the Project.

Comment: What does the Appcombat mean?

Comment: Bro, AppCombat is an android library to add action bar in applications with version level below 3.0. In my opinion, you are using this library but your library project is closed in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Close Eclipse. After that try a full rebuild of all your projects

Projects -> Clean -> Clean All

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build.gradle and change the dependendencies

[image]

Comment: how can i go to my gradle?

Comment: oh your app is not gradle build... so you will have to import the android support v7 as I see in your picture you have the 4th version yo will have to import the new one